# Light speed working on private window(incognito) while not working in normal window of a browser

Tags: wordpress, cache

My site is hosted on lightspeed webserver also using lightspeed plugin for optimization it working for private window but not working on normal window of my browser here is header request of both windows

private window(incognito) Response Header X-Dns-Prefetch-Control: on X-Litespeed-Cache: hit

Normal window Response Header X-lightspeed-cache-Control: private,max-age=1800 X-Litespeed-Cache: miss

please tell me why it is not working on normal window is there any plugin configuration miss or any server configuration is miss?

Light speed cache should work the same as work in private window. In normal window it is missing the hit. Cache should also work in normal window but it is not working.

Comment: Note that browsers will cache things like basic authentication, (broken)  permanent redirects and HSTS headers (even after they have been removed from the site and/or web server configuration) but won't use such cached items in a new incognito browser window. Clearing caches often helps.